# Ruby mediainfo (gem) error "mon out of range"?

Tags: ruby, mediainfo

Trying to use mediainfo ruby gem and get this error (not all files) ... "/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/time.rb:262:in `utc': mon out of range (ArgumentError)"

```
require 'mediainfo'
f = "/<pathtofile>.mp4"
media_info = MediaInfo.from(f)
```

I have tried mediainfo using terminal and works fine, so just the wrapper. I am wondering if I should use it at all as I'm not sure how it works, could I not just get the output straight from mediainfo and pick out what I want ?

> Traceback (most recent call last):    18: from mediainfo.rb:11:in
>   `<main>'  17: from
>   /home/coffee/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/mediainfo-1.3.3/lib/mediainfo.rb:61:in`
>   from'    16: from
>   /home/coffee/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/mediainfo-1.3.3/lib/mediainfo.rb:68:in
>   `from_string'     15: from
>   /home/coffee/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/mediainfo-1.3.3/lib/mediainfo.rb:83:in`
>   from_local_file'     14: from
>   /home/coffee/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/mediainfo-1.3.3/lib/mediainfo.rb:83:in
>   `new'     13: from
>   /home/coffee/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/mediainfo-1.3.3/lib/mediainfo/tracks.rb:37:in`
>   initialize'  12: from
>   /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rexml/element.rb:927:in
>   `each'    11: from
>   /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rexml/xpath.rb:68:in`
>   each'    10: from
>   /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rexml/xpath.rb:68:in
>   `each'     9: from
>   /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rexml/element.rb:927:in`
>   block in each'    8: from
>   /home/coffee/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/mediainfo-1.3.3/lib/mediainfo/tracks.rb:38:in
>   `block in initialize'      7: from
>   /home/coffee/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/mediainfo-1.3.3/lib/mediainfo/tracks.rb:38:in`
>   new'      6: from
>   /home/coffee/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/mediainfo-1.3.3/lib/mediainfo/tracks.rb:82:in
>   `initialize'   5: from
>   /home/coffee/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/mediainfo-1.3.3/lib/mediainfo/tracks.rb:82:in`
>   each'     4: from
>   /home/coffee/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/mediainfo-1.3.3/lib/mediainfo/tracks.rb:86:in
>   `block in initialize'      3: from
>   /home/coffee/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/mediainfo-1.3.3/lib/mediainfo/tracks.rb:112:in`
>   sanitize_element_value'   2: from
>   /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/time.rb:375:in `parse'
>      1: from
>   /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/time.rb:262:in`
>   make_time'
>   /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/time.rb:262:in `utc':
>   mon out of range (ArgumentError)
>   coffee@coffee-MS-7B17:~/Projects/Code/MovieMeta$ ruby mediainfo.rb
>   /media/coffee/big box/Movies/0-9/10,000 BC (2008)-720p.mp4 Traceback
>   (most recent call last):  18: from mediainfo.rb:8:in`'     17:
>   from
>   /home/coffee/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/mediainfo-1.3.3/lib/mediainfo.rb:61:in
>   `from'    16: from
>   /home/coffee/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/mediainfo-1.3.3/lib/mediainfo.rb:68:in`
>   from_string'     15: from
>   /home/coffee/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/mediainfo-1.3.3/lib/mediainfo.rb:83:in
>   `from_local_file'     14: from
>   /home/coffee/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/mediainfo-1.3.3/lib/mediainfo.rb:83:in`
>   new'     13: from
>   /home/coffee/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/mediainfo-1.3.3/lib/mediainfo/tracks.rb:37:in
>   `initialize'  12: from
>   /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rexml/element.rb:927:in`
>   each'    11: from
>   /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rexml/xpath.rb:68:in
>   `each'    10: from
>   /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rexml/xpath.rb:68:in`
>   each'     9: from
>   /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rexml/element.rb:927:in
>   `block in each'    8: from
>   /home/coffee/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/mediainfo-1.3.3/lib/mediainfo/tracks.rb:38:in`
>   block in initialize'      7: from
>   /home/coffee/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/mediainfo-1.3.3/lib/mediainfo/tracks.rb:38:in
>   `new'      6: from
>   /home/coffee/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/mediainfo-1.3.3/lib/mediainfo/tracks.rb:82:in`
>   initialize'   5: from
>   /home/coffee/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/mediainfo-1.3.3/lib/mediainfo/tracks.rb:82:in
>   `each'     4: from
>   /home/coffee/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/mediainfo-1.3.3/lib/mediainfo/tracks.rb:86:in`
>   block in initialize'      3: from
>   /home/coffee/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/mediainfo-1.3.3/lib/mediainfo/tracks.rb:112:in
>   `sanitize_element_value'   2: from
>   /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/time.rb:375:in`parse'
>      1: from
>   /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/time.rb:262:in
>   `make_time'
>   /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/time.rb:262:in`utc':
>   mon out of range (ArgumentError)